# Pulling dynamic data from Sheet2 into Sheet1 then to Sheet3..10

Tags: vba, excel

So I have `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`, `Sheet1` is user set settings and `Sheet2` is a table of values generated by different values in `Sheet1`. Now `Sheet3..10` can be created, which will pull a value from `Sheet2` based on calculations on it.

The problem I'm running in to is when say `Sheet3!H20` is updated from `Sheet2!I15`, how do I get `Sheet3!H20` to have `=VALUE` instead of `=Sheet2!I15` so that `Sheet4..10` can reuse this table?

I have tried `Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)`

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Select Case Sh.Name
        Case "Sheet1"
        Case "Sheet2"
        Case Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("$C$14").Value = "=" & Sh.Range("$D$23").Value

            Sh.Range("$H$20").Value = "=" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("$I$15").Value
    End Select
End Sub
```

But when I do this, it just recalculates constantly and eventually Excel crashes. I have also tried going in to each worksheet with `Worksheet_Calculate` and when I do that I get a runtime error for Range is not in the Worksheet object.

And ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting this code at the start of your macro...

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

then at the end put

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

To ensure that all of the calculations are performed without invoking an endless loop, then try something like this.

1.Declare a global variable called IsCalculating
2.Wrap your code in an if statement

```
if not IsCalculating then
    IsCalculating = true
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    `put your code here`

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.Calculate
    IsCalculating = false
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try the `IsCalculating` variable. To get it to work for the night, I came up with this..

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Sh.Name
        Case "Settings"
        Case "Year To Date"
        Case "Federal Table"
            Select Case ActiveSheet.Name
                Case "Settings"
                Case "Year To Date"
                Case "Federal Table"
                Case "State Table"
                Case "CO Table"
                Case "IA Table"
                Case Else
                    ActiveSheet.Range("$H$20") = "=" & Worksheets("Federal Table").Range("$I$15").Value
            End Select
        Case "State Table"
            Select Case ActiveSheet.Name
                Case "Settings"
                Case "Year To Date"
                Case "Federal Table"
                Case "State Table"
                Case "CO Table"
                Case "IA Table"
                Case Else
                    ActiveSheet.Range("$H$21") = "=" & Worksheets("State Table").Range("$H$6").Value
            End Select
        Case "CO Table"
        Case "IA Table"
        Case Else
            If Worksheets("Federal Table").Range("$C$14").Value <> Sh.Range("$D$23").Value Then
                Worksheets("Federal Table").Range("$C$14").Value = "=" & Sh.Range("$D$23").Value
                Worksheets("State Table").Range("$H$2").Value = "=" & Sh.Range("$D$23").Value
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

But it just looks sloppy to me.

Comment: not entirely sure what you are trying to do either... if you whip up a quick example and send it to me at dcolwell@oasisasset.com.au i will try to give you a decent answer